# Knowing what route the user is on inside TagHelper in .NET Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I am working on a .NET Core application. I have a sidebar with some links. When I click on a particular link, I want to apply the `active` CSS class to its list item.

```
<li class="active ">
  <a href="home/index">
    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
    <span class="title">Home</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I use to be able to do this with Html Helpers in .NET Framework 4.6 but I do not know how to do it in .NET Core. I want the end result of the tag helper to look like this:

```
<sidebarlink controller="home" action="index" icon="home"></sidebarlink>
```

Based on what I did in .NET Framework 4.6, I have made an attempt but I cannot get it to work for the new Tag Helpers.

```
public class SidebarLink : TagHelper
{
  private const string ActiveClass = "active";

  public string Controller { get; set; }

  public string Action { get; set; }

  public string Icon { get; set; }

  public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
  {
    output.TagName = "li";
    var content = await output.GetChildContentAsync();
    content.SetHtmlContent($@"<a href=\"/Controller/Action\"><i class=\"material-icons\">Icon</i><span class=\"title\">Suppliers</span></a>"); // this doesn't work, something is up with the syntax
    // only if I am on the route for the passed controller and action
    // not sure how to check
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", ActiveClass);
  }
}
```

I do not know how I can check and see if I am on the route matching the passed Controller and Action so that I may apply the `active` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following property to your tag helper:

```
[HtmlAttributeNotBound]
[ViewContext]
public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
```

Then, you can get the current controller/action via:

```
var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```